# Using pandas plot to generate a histogram of pre-defined buckets for ages

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df in the form

```
+-------+-----+
| Name  | Age |
+-------+-----+
| John  |  45 |
| Tim   |  29 |
| Elisa |  28 |
| Sarah |  32 |
+-------+-----+
```

I would like to use the `df.plot.hist` functionality to create a histogram, but I want to sort into predetermined age buckets (such as 18-30, 31-45, 46-65, etc) instead of  using `df['Age'].plot.hist(bins=20)` which automatically sets the buckets to be used.

Furthermore, I also want to use percentage distribution rather than frequency distribution. I tried passing `norm=True` but still need help to convert it to  a percentage

Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close! From the docstrings of matplotlib hist (what pandas are using) you have "**bins**: int or sequence or str"

So you can just pass a list of numbers that defines where the splits should be

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot') # makes plot looks much nicer

col_names = ['Name', 'Age']
d = dict(
    Elisa = 28,
    Tim   = 29,
    Sarah = 32,
    John  = 45
)

custom_bins = [18, 31, 42, 66]

df = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=col_names)
df.plot.hist('Age', bins=custom_bins)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for! Do you know how to turn the Y-axis from frequency to percentage distribution? I tried to use `normed=True` but not really sure where to go from there

Comment: use the flag `density=true`. it makes the graph integrate to one. Of you want each column to be percentage, then you should make a bare plot instead.